# Facebook Extension for Firefox

Tags: 12.10, facebook

When I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10, upon starting up Firefox I was asked if I wanted to install the Facebook extension. I clicked yes, and it installed, and it shows up under Empathy Messenger when I click the envelope in the top bar.

Now when I try to go to Facebook, nothing loads, and I get the error message "Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data." I cannot go to Facebook on any web browser after installing this package. Is there a way I can fix this? Or can I remove this Facebook app completely? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

**To completely obliterate the facebook app from your system:**

**Note: your account must be administrator to do these steps** Open up a terminal, enter `sudo apt-get purge unity-webapps-facebookmessenger`. Type in your password (it will not show up, this is normal), then press enter, then when it prompts you, press yes to tell it that no, you really want to remove the app, wait for it to give you something like `username@computer:~$`, then close the window.

Since removing the package misses the .desktop files that create the shortcut, you need to go into the dash, find the app, and drag it to the trash. Alternatively, for people that prefer the command line, find /usr/share/applications, and delete the facebook .desktop file.

Comment: I put in that command, but the icon is still in the dash and appears under the envelope in the top bar. Facebook still will not load.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the unity webapp leaves a shortcut somewhere. I noticed that problem, too.

Comment: It has definitely been removed, so I don't know why the icon is still there.

Facebook still will not load though. I'm getting the same message (unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data).

Comment: Try dragging the icon from the Dash to the Trash.